# Having a script run only when a manually triggered job fails in GitLab

Tags: gitlab-ci, aws-sam

I have the following script that pulls from a remote template. The remote template has the following stages: build, test, code_analysis, compliance, deploy.

The deploy step is manually triggered and executed AWS CLI to deploy a SAM project.

I want to add an additional step such that when the deploy step fails, it will execute a script to rollback the cloudformation stack to its last operational state.

I created a "cleanup-cloudformation-stack-failure" job and tried adding "extends: .deploy", but that didn't work.

I then added an additional stage called "cloudformation_stack_rollback" in the serverless-template.yml file and tried to use a mix of `rules` and `when` to get it to trigger on failure, but I'm getting errors flagged by GitLab's linter.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
include:
  - remote: 'https://my-gitlab-server.com/ci-templates/-/raw/master/serverless-template.yml'

deploy-qas:
  extends: .deploy
  variables:
      ....
  PARAMETER_OVERRIDES: "..."
  environment: qas
  only:
    - qas
  tags:
    - serverless

cleanup-cloudformation-stack-failure:
  variables:
    STACK_NAME: $CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME
  stage: cloudformation_stack_rollback
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_JOB_MANUAL == true'
      when: on_failure
  script:
    - aws cloudformation continue-update-rollback --stack-name ${STACK_NAME} --resources-to-skip ${STACK_NAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot double quotes around `true`, however you can use [Directed Asyclic Graphs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#needs) to execute jobs conditionally

```
include:
  - remote: 'https://my-gitlab-server.com/ci-templates/-/raw/master/serverless-template.yml'

deploy-qas:
  extends: .deploy
  variables:
      ....
  PARAMETER_OVERRIDES: "..."
  environment: qas
  only:
    - qas
  tags:
    - serverless

cleanup-cloudformation-stack-failure:
  needs:
    - deploy-qas
  when: on_failure
  variables:
    STACK_NAME: $CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME
  stage: cloudformation_stack_rollback
  script:
    - aws cloudformation continue-update-rollback --stack-name ${STACK_NAME} --reso
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I fixed the syntax error, but it didn't trigger when the previous job failed.

Comment: I updated my answer, so when the `deploy-qas` job fails `cleanup-cloudformation-stack-failure` will be triggered automatically.

Comment: I tried the new solution. GitLab shows the step is skipped immediately with my primary job being executed. When the primary job failed, the cleanup step remained in "skipped" state.